# Web Services Advise Java 

Tags: java, web-services, compiler-construction, cmd

I am reading a book about Java and Web Services, but I am stuck in the first example of the book. Look at this codes, and please tell me how would you go for running this classes and how or where would you save them. With out using any IDE!

Time Server class

```
    package web.ts;  // time server

    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.jws.WebMethod;
    import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
    import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

  /**
  *  The annotation @WebService signals that this is the
  *  SEI (Service Endpoint Interface). @WebMethod signals 
  *  that each method is a service operation.
  *
  *  The @SOAPBinding annotation impacts the under-the-hood
  *  construction of the service contract, the WSDL
  *  (Web Services Definition Language) document. Style.RPC
  *  simplifies the contract and makes deployment easier.
  */

    @WebService
    @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC) // more on this later
    public interface TimeServer {
    @WebMethod String getTimeAsString();
    @WebMethod long getTimeAsElapsed();
    }
```

TimeServerImpl
           package web.ts;

```
       import java.util.Date;
       import javax.jws.WebService;

 /**
 *  The @WebService property endpointInterface links the
 *  SIB (this class) to the SEI (ch01.ts.TimeServer).
 *  Note that the method implementations are not annotated
 *  as @WebMethods.
 */
     @WebService(endpointInterface = "ch01.ts.TimeServer")
     public class TimeServerImpl implements TimeServer {
     public String getTimeAsString() { return new Date().toString(); }
     public long getTimeAsElapsed() { return new Date().getTime(); }
     }
```

and then the last class
the TimeServerPublisher
         package web.ts;

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

    /**
* This application publishes the web service whose
* SIB is ch01.ts.TimeServerImpl. For now, the 
* service is published at network address 127.0.0.1.,
* which is localhost, and at port number 9876, as this
* port is likely available on any desktop machine. The
* publication path is /ts, an arbitrary name.
*
* The Endpoint class has an overloaded publish method.
* In this two-argument version, the first argument is the
* publication URL as a string and the second argument is
* an instance of the service SIB, in this case
* ch01.ts.TimeServerImpl.
*
* The application runs indefinitely, awaiting service requests.
* It needs to be terminated at the command prompt with control-C
* or the equivalent.
*
* Once the applicatation is started, open a browser to the URL
*
*     http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts?wsdl
*
* to view the service contract, the WSDL document. This is an
* easy test to determine whether the service has deployed
* successfully. If the test succeeds, a client then can be
* executed against the service.
*/
public class TimeServerPublisher {
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
  // 1st argument is the publication URL
  // 2nd argument is an SIB instance
  Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts", new TimeServerImpl());
 }
 }
```

I know how to compile them. But something goes wrong when i try to run the publisher.

The way that i have saved them is in a folder called Web/ts/"and here the three classes"

Comment: If you're learning Java then I'd suggest you **do** use an IDE. It will help you to focus on learning the language without having to worry so much about environment issues.

Comment: "But something goes wrong when i try to run the publisher." - what does it mean? Compilation error? Runtme error? Something else?

Comment: I suggest you to start learning by using IDE like eclipse. It will help you a lot in understanding etc. After running some initial examples you can code it without IDE.

Comment: I know how use an IDE, the problem is that I need to do it with out the IDE. The error when I try to run the publisher class in the cmd form windows, it say it could not find a main class called TimeServerPublisher. But it can compile it.

Comment: @helloThere: Compiling and running are two different tasks. Can you show how you start the main method (command line + arguments)? Why do you have to do it without an IDE?

Comment: @Home yes I know they are two different things. My main concern is that my folder structure is wrong or something. I firs compile all the files, that is the three java files, using javac web/ts/*.java and then I try o use java web/ts/namehere but it says i could not find the main class to run the file. Im sure my location is correct, im newbie on doing things from cmd, so that is im a bit lost. I also tried with IDE i could not make i work.

Comment: Try `java -cp . web.ts.TimeServerPublisher`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, interface file and the impl file can be in different folders(under your src folder), but the @WebService(endpointInterface = "ch01.ts.TimeServer") path to the interface file should be shown correctly. Once this path is correct, the publishing should happend and the wsdl should get generated.

Comment: Wow man, good eye!! I just noticed the error from Eclipse this time, and then saw your comment and finally made it work. I though my mistake was something about the folder structure. I had changed the names and that is why it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn Webservices I suggest you download an existing framework like [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) or [Apache axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/). They include many samples which you can compile and run. The samples are easy to understand and you will have from the beginning something that works.
They also give you reasonably good structure for the project, so you know where to put xml and wsdl files, etc.

And yes, you don't need an IDE to run them. From my experience it's better to start without IDE, so you know exactly what is going on. An IDE will boost your productivity later.

Comment: Thanx for your feed back. This I am just doing this on perpuse for a specific reason. My problem is that Im not sure if my folder structure is proper, since I always let the IDE do my project I have never try to do one by my self from scratch

Comment: axis2 is more mature. cxf is probably easier to learn. It's up to you to decide